# Show that in a topological space $\partial\partial A \subset \partial A$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following task:

> Show that in topological space $\partial\partial A \subset \partial A$,
>   where $\partial A$ denotes the set of boundary points of $A$, that is
>   $\partial A = \overline{A}\;\setminus\;A^o$, where $\overline{A}$ is
>   the closure of $A$ and $A^o$ is the set of interior points of $A$.
>   Give an example of $A$ such that $\partial \partial A \neq \partial
>  A$.

I tried to solve this but I resulted in equality $\partial \partial A = \partial A$, I'm not sure where I went wrong. Here's what I tried:

By the definition of $\partial A$ we have $\partial A\;\cup A^o = \overline{A}$, that is $A^o$ is the open complement of $\partial A$ in $\overline{A}$. Now

$$\partial \partial A = \overline{\partial A}\;\setminus\; (\partial A)^o = \overline{\partial A}.$$

Now because $\partial A$ is closed in $\overline{A}$ then $\partial A$ is the smallest closed set containing $\partial A$, that is $\overline{\partial A}=\partial A$, so

$$\partial \partial A = \overline{\partial A}=\partial A,$$

that is $\partial \partial A = \partial A$

I know I did a mistake in some point...

Comment: Could you show us your proof?

Comment: Yes I can, it's not correct then but I'll add it anyway :)

Comment: $A = \mathbb{Q}$ shows that equality does not hold in general.

Comment: NB The above duplicate also gives an easy way to construct a set with proper inclusion: Just look for a set whose boundary has nonempty interior, such as @menag's example.

Comment: The boundary of a set is always closed, hence equal to its closure, which gives the containment you want. However, the boundary of a set does not always have empty interior. If it does have nonempty interior, then the second boundary operation removes points, which gives strict containment.

Comment: Thank you @Ian I see now my mistake.

Comment: P.S. should I close this question, if it's duplicate..